# What is more cost effective updating a mesh or removing and adding from the scene?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, mesh

I have a small web app that I've designed for viewing bathymetric data of the seafloor in Three.js.  Basically I am using a loader to bring in JSON models of the my extruded bathymetry into my scene and allowing the user to rotate the model or click next to load a new part of the seafloor.

All of my models have the same 2D footprint so are identical in two dimensions, only elevations and texture change from model to model.

My question is this:  What is the most cost effective way to update my model?

1. Using `scene.remove(mesh);` then calling my loader again to load a new model and then adding it to the scene with `scene.add(mesh);`.
2. Updating the existing mesh by calling my loader to bring in material and geometry and then calling `mesh.geometry = geometry;`, `mesh.material = material` and then `mesh.geometry.needsUpdate;`.

I've heard that updating is pretty intensive from a computational point of view, but all of the articles that I've read on this state that the two methods are almost the same.  Is this information correct?  Is there a better way to approach my code in this instance?

An alternative that I've considered is skipping the step where I create the model (in Blender) and instead using a displacement map to update the y coordinates of my vertices.  Then to update I could push new vertices on an existing plane geometry before replacing the material.  Would this be a sound approach?  At the very least I think the displacement map would be a smaller file to load than a .JSON file.  I could even optimize the display by loading a GUI element to divide the mesh into more or fewer divisions for high or low quality render...

Comment: I think this might be off-topic, as the answers are likely to be completely opinion based.

Comment: I see your point, I had a bit of an epiphany at the end there.  Using a displacement map is WAY more efficient than loading in new models.  

My question still stands though.  Which is the better method, updating an existing mesh with new texture and geometry or simply removing and adding it from the scene?

Comment: You might be better off asking this in a 3D modelling forum? I would've thought most JS users here on SO are web developers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know off the top of my head what exactly happens under the hood, but from what i remember i think these two are the exact same thing.

You aren't updating the existing mesh. A mesh extends from Object3D, so it just sits there, wiring some geometry and some materials.

`mesh.geometry = geometry` did not "update the mesh", or it did, but with new geometry (which may be the thing you are actually referring to as mesh).

In other words, you always have your container, but when you replace the geometry by doing `=geometry` you set it up for all sorts of GL calls in the next THREE.WebGLRenderer.render() call.

Where that new geometry gets attached to, be it an existing mesh, or a new one, shouldnt matter at all. The geometry is the thing that will trigger the low level webgl calls like `gl.bufferData()`.

```
//upload two geometries to the gpu on first render()
var meshA = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1) );

var meshB = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1) ); 

//upload one geometry to the gpu on first render()
var bg = new THREE.BoxGeometry()

var meshA = new THREE.Mesh( bg );
var meshB = new THREE.Mesh( bg );

for ( var i = 0 ; i < someBigNumber ; i ++ ){
  var meshTemp = new THREE.Mesh( bg );
}
//doesnt matter that you have X meshes, you only have one geometry

//1 mesh two geometries / "computations"

var meshA = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry() ); //first computation - compute box geometry
scene.add(meshA);
renderer.render( scene , camera ); //upload box to the gpu

meshA.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry();
renderer.render( scene , camera); //upload sphere to the gpu
```

`THREE.Mesh` seems to be the most confusing concept in three.js.